# R - date sequence as dataframe column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe

```
dt <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2),
    start = c(as.Date("2020-08-01"), as.Date("2019-11-01")),
    end = c(Sys.Date(), as.Date("2020-02-01")),
  )
```

I'd like to crate date sequence between start and end columns for each id. So result should be

```
dt <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2),
    start = c(as.Date("2020-08-01"), as.Date("2019-11-01")),
    end = c(Sys.Date(), as.Date("2020-02-01")),
    result = c("8/20, 9/20, 10/20", "11/19, 12/19, 1/20, 2/20")
  )
```

Where result is formatted as m/y where leading zeroes in months are removed and year is formatted as two digits number. I prefer dplyr solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a monthly sequence from `start` to `end` for each row and use `format` to get data in required format.

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = toString(trimws(format(
                     seq(start, end, by = 'month'), '%m/%y'), 'left', '0')))

#     id start      end        result                  
#  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <chr>                   
#1     1 2020-08-01 2020-10-23 8/20, 9/20, 10/20       
#2     2 2019-11-01 2020-02-01 11/19, 12/19, 1/20, 2/20
```

You can also implement this logic in base R :

```
dt$result <- mapply(function(x, y) 
         toString(trimws(format(seq(x, y, by = 'month'), '%m/%y'), 'left', '0')),
         dt$start, dt$end)
```

Comment: Instead of `rowwise() ...` you might use `mutate(result = map2_chr(.x = start, .y = end, .f = f)`, where `f` is your function.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> library(purrr)
> library(dplyr)
> dt %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(result = map2(start, end, seq, by = 'month')) %>% unnest(result) %>% 
+   mutate(result = paste(month(result),substr(year(result), nchar(year(result))-1, nchar(year(result))), sep = '/')) %>% 
+   group_by(id, start, end) %>% summarise(result = toString(result))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'id', 'start' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   id, start [2]
     id start      end        result                  
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <chr>                   
1     1 2020-08-01 2020-10-23 8/20, 9/20, 10/20       
2     2 2019-11-01 2020-02-01 11/19, 12/19, 1/20, 2/20
```